# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir un ciclo haciendo uso de document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo una duda con este código,
mi intención es llenar un array de 20 espacios (coloque 2 a modo prueba) para ejecutarlo. Una vez que este lleno me gustaría que mostrara 3 valores, el array original, el array de valores al cuadrado y el del cubo.

El problema es que me gustaría imprimirlo mediante un get.ElementbyId, de forma que aparezca cuando termine de completar los números con el prompt, pero así como lo tengo no me imprime nada :(. No sé como hacer el llamado correctamente.

De antemano, muchísimas gracias por su colaboración.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Array</title>
   
</head>
<script>
    let original = new Array(2);
    let cuadrado  = new Array(20);
    let cubo  = new Array(20);
function recorrer_array() {
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        original[i] = prompt('Introduce un número: ');
    }

    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
    cuadrado[i] = original[i]*original[i];
        cubo[i] =original[i]*original[i]*original[i]; 
    }
}

function imprimir_original(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_orig').innerHTML = original[i];
    }
}

function imprimir_cuadrado(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_cuad').innerHTML = cuadrado[i];
    }
}

function imprimir_cubo(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_cub').innerHTML = cubo[i];
    }
}

</script>
<body>
        <div id="contenidoCentro">
                <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                        <div id="ContenidoColumna1">
                            <h1 class="blanco">Array</h1>
            
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                            <div id="ContenidoColumna2">
                                <h2>Se necesita un sistema que almacena 20 números en tres diferentes arreglos, en el primero
                                        se almacena el número tal cual se tecleo, en el segundo se almacena el cuadrado de dicho número
                                        y en el tercero su cubo.
                                        </h2>
                                <h3>Instrucciones: Haz click en el botón "Ingresar números" y llena los 20 números para conocer su <em>original, cuadrado y cubo.</em> </h3>
                                <center>
                                <button type="button" onclick="recorrer_array()">Ingresar números</button> <br><br>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Original:</td>
                                        <td><div id="imprimir_orig"></div></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cuadrado:</td>
                                        <td><div id="imprimir_cuad"></div></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cubo:</td>
                                        <td><div id="imprimir_cub"></div></td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                    </div>    
     
        
        </div>

        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes hacerlo asi:
primero no estas llamando a las funciones segundos debes usar `.innerHTML +=` para que haga un append
si no solo imprimira el ultimo valor!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Array</title>
   
</head>
<script>
    let original = new Array(2);
    let cuadrado  = new Array(20);
    let cubo  = new Array(20);
function recorrer_array() {
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        original[i] = prompt('Introduce un número: ');
    }

    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
    cuadrado[i] = Math.pow(original[i], 2);
        cubo[i] = Math.pow(original[i], 3);
    }
   imprimir_original();
   imprimir_cuadrado();
   imprimir_cubo();
}

function imprimir_original(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_orig').innerHTML += original[i];
    }
}

function imprimir_cuadrado(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_cuad').innerHTML += cuadrado[i];
    }
}

function imprimir_cubo(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_cub').innerHTML += cubo[i];
    }
}

</script>
<body>
        <div id="contenidoCentro">
                <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                        <div id="ContenidoColumna1">
                            <h1 class="blanco">Array</h1>
            
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                            <div id="ContenidoColumna2">
                                <h2>Se necesita un sistema que almacena 20 números en tres diferentes arreglos, en el primero
                                        se almacena el número tal cual se tecleo, en el segundo se almacena el cuadrado de dicho número
                                        y en el tercero su cubo.
                                        </h2>
                                <h3>Instrucciones: Haz click en el botón "Ingresar números" y llena los 20 números para conocer su <em>original, cuadrado y cubo.</em> </h3>
                                <center>
                                <button type="button" onclick="recorrer_array()">Ingresar números</button> <br><br>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Original:</td>
                                        <td><div id="imprimir_orig"></div></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cuadrado:</td>
                                        <td><div id="imprimir_cuad"></div></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cubo:</td>
                                        <td><div id="imprimir_cub"></div></td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                    </div>    
     
        
        </div>

        
</body>
</html>
```

**o puedes hacerlo asi que es mucho mas facil y ordenado:**

```js
let original = new Array(2);

function recorrer_array() {
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        original[i] = prompt('Introduce un número: ');
    }

   imprimir('imprimir_orig');
   imprimir('imprimir_cuad',2);
   imprimir('imprimir_cub',3);
}
// creamos una funcion que se llama imprimir que recibe el elemento a seleccionar y el exponente
// por defecto 1 que es sin exponente en caso de que no se envie ninguno
function imprimir(el,exp=1){
    // recorremos el arreglo
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        // seleccionamos el elemento enviado y hace un append del resultado
        document.getElementById(el).textContent +=Math.pow(original[i], exp) +" ";
    }
}
```

```html
        <div id="contenidoCentro">
                <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                        <div id="ContenidoColumna1">
                            <h1 class="blanco">Array</h1>
            
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                            <div id="ContenidoColumna2">
                                <h2>Se necesita un sistema que almacena 20 números en tres diferentes arreglos, en el primero
                                        se almacena el número tal cual se tecleo, en el segundo se almacena el cuadrado de dicho número
                                        y en el tercero su cubo.
                                        </h2>
                                <h3>Instrucciones: Haz click en el botón "Ingresar números" y llena los 20 números para conocer su <em>original, cuadrado y cubo.</em> </h3>
                                <center>
                                <button type="button" onclick="recorrer_array()">Ingresar números</button> <br><br>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Original:</td>
                                        <td><div id="imprimir_orig"></div></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cuadrado:</td>
                                        <td><div id="imprimir_cuad"></div></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cubo:</td>
                                        <td><div id="imprimir_cub"></div></td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                    </div>    
     
        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verificando un poco tu codigo, he visto que no llamabas los metodos que necesitabas. Tambien te he comentado un poco para que veas lo que hecho.

```js
let original = new Array(2);
let cuadrado  = new Array(20);
let cubo  = new Array(20);
function recorrer_array() {
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        original[i] = prompt('Introduce un número: ');
    }

    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        cuadrado[i] = original[i]*original[i];
        cubo[i] =original[i]*original[i]*original[i]; 
    }
    //no te hacia nada ya que no llamabas los metodos necesarios
    imprimir_original();
    imprimir_cuadrado();
    imprimir_cubo();
}

function imprimir_original(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        //tienes que concatenar los elementos, para eso utiliza +=, con = simplemente se mostraria el ultimo elemento
        document.getElementById('imprimir_orig').innerHTML += original[i] ;
        if(!isUltimoNumero(i, original)){
            document.getElementById('imprimir_orig').innerHTML += ", ";
        }
    }
}

function imprimir_cuadrado(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_cuad').innerHTML += cuadrado[i];
        if(!isUltimoNumero(i, original)){
            document.getElementById('imprimir_cuad').innerHTML += ", ";
        }
    }
}

function imprimir_cubo(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_cub').innerHTML += cubo[i] + " ";
        if(!isUltimoNumero(i, original)){
            document.getElementById('imprimir_cub').innerHTML += ", ";
        }
    }
}

//metodo que verifica si es ultimo numero de array o no (para poner comas separadoras)
function isUltimoNumero(pos, array){
    if((pos + 1) != array.length){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenidoCentro">
    <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
        <div id="ContenidoColumna1">
            <h1 class="blanco">Array</h1>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
        <div id="ContenidoColumna2">
            <h2>Se necesita un sistema que almacena 20 números en tres diferentes arreglos, en el primero
                se almacena el número tal cual se tecleo, en el segundo se almacena el cuadrado de dicho número
                y en el tercero su cubo.
            </h2>
            <h3>Instrucciones: Haz click en el botón "Ingresar números" y llena los 20 números para conocer su <em>original,
                    cuadrado y cubo.</em> </h3>
            <center>
                <button type="button" onclick="recorrer_array()">Ingresar números</button> <br><br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Original:</td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="imprimir_orig"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Cuadrado:</td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="imprimir_cuad"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Cubo:</td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="imprimir_cub"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Espero que te sirva!

**AÑADIDO**
Si me permites se podría mejorar tu código utilizando solo una array.
Algo así:

```js
let original = new Array(2);
function recorrer_array() {
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        original[i] = prompt('Introduce un número: ');
    }
    //no te hacia nada ya que no llamabas los metodos necesarios
    imprimir_original();
    imprimir_cuadrado();
    imprimir_cubo();
}

function imprimir_original(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        //tienes que concatenar los elementos, para eso utiliza +=, con = simplemente se mostraria el ultimo elemento
        document.getElementById('imprimir_orig').innerHTML += original[i];
        if(!isUltimoNumero(i, original)){
            document.getElementById('imprimir_orig').innerHTML += ", ";
        }
    }
}

function imprimir_cuadrado(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_cuad').innerHTML += original[i]**2;
        if(!isUltimoNumero(i, original)){
            document.getElementById('imprimir_cuad').innerHTML += ", ";
        }
    }
}

function imprimir_cubo(){
    for (let i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('imprimir_cub').innerHTML += original[i]**3;
        if(!isUltimoNumero(i, original)){
            document.getElementById('imprimir_cub').innerHTML += ", ";
        }
    }
}

//metodo que verifica si es ultimo numero de array o no (para poner comas separadoras)
function isUltimoNumero(pos, array){
    if((pos + 1) != array.length){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

P.D.: en JS si pones `4**5`, lo que realmente haces es elevar el 4 a 5.